# Removing Git commits on a branch

Tags: git, git-rebase, git-subtree

How do I remove commits that are branched off `master`?

I have added a large library, along with a very rich commit history (and that predates my code) to a subdirectory via [Git subtree](https://github.com/apenwarr/git-subtree). I'd like to retroactively squash that entire history, *but still be able to merge in new commits to the library*.

I have tried various combinations of `git rebase` but I never get the expected result [*].

My repository looks something like:

```
A---B-----------F---G master
               /
  ... C---D---E
```

and I'd like for it to look something like:

```
A---B-----------F'--G' master
               /
              E'
```

or:

```
A---B-------E'--F'--G' master
```

[*]:

- `git rebase --onto C E master`
- `git checkout F; git rebase --onto C E master`

Comment: Merging will be impaired by such squashing. Why do you want to squash it? Just to clean up gitk/git log output?

Comment: Yes, that and the fact that all the prior commits amount to several hundred megabytes.

Comment: Your decision to import a library by integrating its development history in the project repository is strange.

Comment: Are sure that limiting it to the last commit will economise much space?

Comment: For cleaner output you can use submodules. To save space you can try to clone that library in shallow mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. This is history editing. You will end up in something like

   ```
   A---B-----------F'---G' master
                  /
                 E'
   ```
2. Merging will be a problem after this, because of Git will not be able to find common parents between your history and libraries's history.
3. To actually do it you need to

   1. Reset to B (creating tag or branch for G to keep it around)
   2. Perform merge with `--no-commit`.
   3. Rebase or cherry-pick G here (it will be G')

   The history will look like

   ```
   A---B-----------F'---G'
   ```

---

To make the shallow clone of the library, you need to do something like this (Warning: untested):

1. Save commits from F (not including) to G (including) to a patch (`git format-patch F --stdout > ~/saved_commits.patch`)
2. Reset to B. Ensure there are no branches that are poiting to F, E or G
3. Remove the remote together with it's ref namespace `git remote rm`
4. Erase reflogs: `git reflog expire --expire=now --all`
5. Actually remove things from git: `git gc --prune=now`. Now you should see the repository shrank.
6. Re-add the remote for library.
7. `git fetch --depth=10 libraryremote`
8. Repeat the merge (the usual way)
9. Apply saved commits (`git am ~/saved_commits.patch`).

---

To migrate into submodules solution (the best option probably), you need to rollback to the state before merge and set up submodules, then substitute each merge with changed commit-id for submodule. Unlike for the [case of splitting out project directory to submodule](https://gist.github.com/753824) I don't know the automated solution for this (but it can be implemented the similar way).

Comment: Why can't `E'` have `F`, not `F'`, as its parent (same goes for `F'` and `G`)?

Comment: Commit number == commit hash. Changing parent means changing this commit means changing this commit's hash means changing this commit's number. History edit makes ripple that changes all commits up the the most recent.

Comment: Here (point 3.) are instructions to do what you state in the question, but it will break merging. What do you want more? 1. Exact commands how to do it; or 2. Ideas how to switch to submodules; or 3. Ideas how to make the library cloned shallowly?

Comment: Thanks @vi. I think I'd like to clone the library shallowly. I used to have the library as a submodule, but changed over to a subtree because it seemed more easy to manage (I was wrong!). I'm trying to reintroduce it as a submodule using various `filter-branch` commands, but I'd like to see what a shallow clone entails.