# Git branch remove commits

Tags: git, github

There is a public github project I would like to contribute to. To do this I need to fork the repository, make my changes and then do a pull request.

Where this started to go wrong was that I had no idea how to use git beyond a very basic understanding of things and promptly made changes to my main branch. So I have some changes in the main branch that are in 1 pull request. As far as I am aware if I just delete my fork and start again my existing PR will be destroyed.

I want to introduce a second PR (which is now on it's own branch) however the branch it's on is off of my main fork so it has some changes from the previous work on it which I do not want to go into the next PR.

I have the following changes:
A-B-C-D-E-F

I made a new branch before D and only want changes D, E and F on that branch. Is it possible to achieve what I want?

I suspect this is probably a problem that has been addressed many times however I am struggling finding an answer. I have looked at [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18912723/git-remove-commits-between-branches) [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9472116/removing-git-commits-on-a-branch) questions however they do not seem to have what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new branch, checkout it, then `git cherry-pick D E F`.